# How to pass a python variables to shell script in azure databricks notebookbles.?

Tags: python, azure, variables, databricks

How to pass a python variables from %python cmd to shell script %sh,in azure databricks notebook..?

[image: notebook example]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per my experience, there are two workaround ways to pass a Python variable to Bash script for your current scenario.

Here is my sample codes using Python3 in notebook.

1. To pass little data via environment variable in the same shell session of Azure Databricks Notebook, as below.

   ```
   %python
   import os
   l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
   os.environ['LIST'] = ' '.join(l)
   print(os.getenv('LIST'))

   %%bash
   for i in $LIST
   do
     echo $i
   done
   ```

It works as the figure below.

[image]

2. To pass large data via file in the current path of Azure Databricks Notebook, as below.

   ```
   %python
   with open('varL.txt', 'w') as f:
     for elem in l:
       f.write(elem+'\n')
     f.close()  

   %%bash
   pwd
   ls -lh varL.txt
   echo '=======show content=========='
   cat varL.txt
   echo '=====result of script========'
   for i in $(cat varL.txt)
   do
     echo $i
   done
   ```

It works as the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your explanation!

Comment: How would one do this if you didn't want to hardcode the name of the environment variable? In cmd 2 in the first way, you hardcode the name LIST in $LIST. Is there anyway that the name for LIST could be stored in a python variable and evaluated within the bash script? Like `x = 'LIST'` and you do something like `for i in $x` in the bash script. In my experience, this doesn't work.